# Reshaping a nested Numpy Arrays using reshape

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array :

```
ar = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

I want to convert it to :

```
ar = [[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]
```

I have tried numpy reshape function it did not work.
Is there any way to reshape it using numpy reshape method or any other way??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Transpose (.T)

```
ar = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
ar.T
```

Comment: `.T` is _transpose_, not _transformation_.